# How to open/close index of a node with Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/_open'
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/_close'
```

How to achieve this with the Java API?
I have Googled lot but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Playing around in eclipse, it looks like it should be something like this:

```
client.admin().indices().close(new CloseIndexRequest("test"));
client.admin().indices().open(new OpenIndexRequest("test"));
```

Comment: Thanks buddy.Almost there. client.admin().indices().close(Requests.closeIndexRequest("test"))
Thanks for help.. !!

Comment: `CloseIndexResponse closeIndexResponse = client.admin().indices().close(Requests.closeIndexRequest(index)).actionGet();` a closeIndexResponse.isAcknowledged() to check the result ?